# Pass a variable to a sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I have been working on this sed command for a while now, the command should search and replace any input like this one in a file passed a parameter to my shell script :

```
${GDATEF(-4D,ddMMyyyy)}
```

It should replace it by the current date minus or plus the number before D (here it will be current date -4 days )

So far I have managed to do it for a specific string but I don't know how to do it by passing a file as a parmaeter :

*Shell script that works only for one string :

```
sed '
      s/D,ddMMyyyy)\}/ days\\\\\"\ \+\\\\\"%d\/%m\/%Y\\\\\"/g;
      s/\${GDATEF(/date -d \\\\\"`date` + /g;
      s/date -d /date -d/g;
      s/\\//ge;
      ' <<<'${GDATEF(-4D,ddMMyyyy)}'
```

The ouput of this is : 16/10/2021 as expected

Now what i want to do is pass a file as a parmeter and replace any string that matches with the result of my sed command.

I have tried this but it throws an unterminated command error, I think I have a quoting issue but i could not find it.

```
sed  -i "
      s/D,ddMMyyyy)\}/ days\\\\\"\ \+\\\\\"%d\/%m\/%Y\\\\\"/g;
      s/\${GDATEF(/date -d \\\\\"`date` + /g;
      s/date -d /date -d/g;
      s/\\//ge;
      " $1
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: I have tried with single quotes there are 2 errors : Error 1: my file does not get updated it turns empty. However shell terminal displays the content of the file but with Error2 : without executing the command that should give the date. Here is an example : date -d"`date` + 0d,ddMMyyyy)} now if you execute that you get the date expected.

Comment: Which command does it say is unterminated?  The 2nd?   The backslashes are out of hand and likely mean that you'd be a lot better off alternating double and single quotes rather than trying to use one and escape the others.

Comment: `it throws an unterminated command error,` Please post verbatim the error message. `I think I have a quoting issue` So use `'` not `"`, why did you change them quotes? Check your scripts with shellcheck. And, as said, using `e` is _very unsafe_ and hard, and you will spent your time on it. Instead, use python and be done with it in an hour.

Comment: First make the command easier. Your working `sed` example only accepts 1 fixed format, so why all the trouble? You only use the `-4` in the string `${GDATEF(-4D,ddMMyyyy)}`. When I test your `sed` without the `e` option, I get a call to date inside the date command.

Comment: You should not solve your problem (show a sample inputfile!) with `sed`, so the next improvement is just one step in the wrong direction: `sed -r 's#\$\{GDATEF\(([^D]+)D,ddMMyyyy\)}#date -d "\1 days" +"%d/%m/%Y"#e' <<<'${GDATEF(-4D,ddMMyyyy)}'`

Comment: Guys I am launching this inside a docker container that does not have python and only minimalistic shell so yeah I know that ideally it would be better to ask another question but this is the question I need an answer for because I have some restrictions that I don't control...